# Как добавить возможность перемещения приложения на SD карту?

Tags: android

Привет, некоторые приложения можно перенести на SD карту. У меня эта кнопка недоступна. Как добавить эту возможность в своё приложение?

Answer (score 1):

Я нашёл. Надо добавить атрибут android:installLocation="auto" в манифест приложения возле package, то есть туда, где тэг